# No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to get the width and height of the image, ImageView variable is **iv**. But it seems like I always get below error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:37)
at com.example.backup.contour_image.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:56)
```

**My Code**

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    Bitmap bm =((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    int w = iv.getWidth();
    int h = iv.getHeight();

    mRgba = new Mat(w,h,CvType.CV_8UC4); <---- the error of line being described

    int cols = mRgba.cols();
    int rows = mRgba.rows();

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
}
```

Comment: did you configure opencv correctly with anroid IDE?.it seemed like the IDE could not find path for library .a or .so files

Comment: Yes it is configured right. mRgba is Mat type.